# Convergence of a special series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I know a series $A$ converges to $a$

and a series $B$ converges to $b$.

I need help in proving that

> $(A-B)^{2}$ converges to $(a-b)^{2}$

Comment: The easiest way is probably to use continuity of the map $y\mapsto y^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a direct proof. Let $\epsilon>0$. Since $A$ and $B$ converge, they are both bounded, say $|a_n| \le M$ and $|b_n| \le P$. Note this also implies $|a| \le M$ and $|b| \le P$. By definition of limit, there exists $N$ such that for $n \ge N$.

\begin{align}
|a_n - a| < 
\frac{\epsilon}{4P+4M} \\
|b_n - B| < \frac{\epsilon}{4P+4M}
\end{align}

Then

$$
|(a_n-b_n)^2 - (a-b)^2| = |(a_n - b_n - a + b)(a_n - b_n + a -b)| = |a_n - a -b_n + b||a_n + a - b_n -b| \le |a_n - a -b_n + b|(2P + 2M) \le (|a_n -a| + |b_n -b|)(2P+2M) < \left(2\frac{\epsilon}{4P+4M}\right)(2P+2M) = \epsilon
$$

Alternately, one could simply applied result the sums, differences, products, and quotients of convergent sequence are convergent with the sum, difference, product, quotient of the limit. (i.e. $A - B$ converges to $a - b$, then $(A-B)^2 = (A-B)*(A-B)$ converges to $(a-b)^2$.